# Significato di "è suonata la campana" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Dopo cena sentii la padrona fare a sua figlia: – Ce l’hai il velo, Ginotta? Pigliamo la strada e andiamo a pregare noi due a Cappelletto. Se non chiediamo perdono noi per lui, c’è posto che stanotte nostro Signore ci mandi del male a noi o alla campagna.
>         Tobia era giusto sull’uscio e le fece penare un po’ a passare, ma poi si schivò e disse loro dietro: – **È suonata la campana**, o due bagasce?

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "è suonata la campana" in questo testo? Ho cercato alla voce "campana" in parecchi dizionari, incluso il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli, ma non ho trovato nessun riferimento all'espressione "suonare la campana" in senso figurato. Si tratta semplicemente di uno scherno fatto da Tobia al comportamento bigotto di queste due donne? Cioè, il significato sarebbe più o meno questo: "uscite perché è suonata la campana della chiesa o perché siete due bagasce"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il suono delle campane ha [scandito per secoli il ritmo delle giornate](http://www.caivaldarnosuperiore.it/il-suono-delle-campane-ha-scandito-per-secoli-il-ritmo-delle-giornate-dei-nostri-montanari/) (e della vita) degli abitanti dei monti e delle campagne.

Infatti Tobia schernisce le due donne con disprezzo e chiede se fosse suonata la campana della chiesa, l'unico momento in cui le donne potevano giustificare il sottrarsi al duro lavoro dei campi e nelle cascine.

L'espressione "o due bagasce" è una sorta di intercalare molto dispregiativo per rivolgersi alle due donne.

In dialetto ligure (ma non solo) la parola [bagascia](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bagascia/) significa:

> s. f. [dal provenz. ant. *bagassa*, fr. ant. *baiasse*, fr. mod. *bagasse*
>   «servente, fanciulla, bagascia», di etimo incerto] (pl. -sce), spreg.
>   – Sgualdrina, puttana

Nell'[opera di Fenoglio](http://www.centrostudibeppefenoglio.it/it/articolo/1-5-27/beppe-fenoglio/le-opere/la-malora) la condizione della donna nel mondo contadino viene così descritta:

> Ne *La malora* nessuno si salva dalla maledizione, neppure le donne, che
>   sono sfruttate fino all’esaurimento di ogni energia: esse trascorrono
>   la loro esistenza nel lavoro e nella preghiera, che è la religiosa ed
>   istintiva accettazione della sofferenza, l’invocazione di un Dio
>   lontano, inavvertibile.

Comment: Quindi, questo "o" non è la congiunzione?

Comment: Intendi veramente un “intercalare”? (“Parola, esclamazione, frase che qualcuno ha l’abitudine, più o meno inconscia, di ripetere spesso nel discorso, senza necessità: _ha uno strano, un noioso intercalare_”, [Treccani](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/intercalare1))

Comment: Un'“apostrofe”, forse? Comunque sembra anche a me che quel “o” sia l'interiezione, anche se sa un po' di toscanismo.

Comment: Sicuramente la _o_ qui non è una congiunzione. Non mi sovveniva il termine preciso e tecnico per definire l'uso della _o_ come un'evocazione, come, ad esempio, "O Giovinezza", "O mio babbino caro". Ben accetti suggerimenti

Comment: Sarebbe come l'«o Tosco» che appare nell'*Inferno* di Dante. Veramente questa interiezione si trova qualche altra volta ne *La malora*. Per esempio: «Tutto quello che vedo posso comprarmelo. O buona gente, posso farvi diventar tutti miei mezzadri».